# How do I fix a missing skylight?

Tags: roof, skylight

A windstorm took my skylight a while back and I never got around to fixing it. How should I repair the rot and prevent further damage?[image]

Comment: Is your goal "close the hole" or "install a new skylight"?

Comment: Check if there is any rot first, it might just be peeling paint.  If rot, then it should be removed and replace with new wood.  Covering and sealing the opening would be good, either with new skylight or roof.

Comment: You probably need to further assess the damage & how it's installed, from on the roof. If water was getting into the bits you *can* see, you definitely need to check where you *can't*, like the flashing etc.

Comment: I’d like to leave it open actually. A replacement sky light isn’t easy to find in that size. I’m mainly concerned that the rot will spread and cause much bigger problem.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Gard. Please [merge your accounts](//diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so you have access to edit, comment, and accept answers on your own question. Note that posting responses as answers can result in an [automated lock](//diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) that can prevent others from assisting you.

Comment: How long ago was "a while back" and what kind of protection has been over this opening in your roof since? There could be fairly significant damage to the structure of the roof if it's rained (even once) since then...

Answer (score 2):

You have several issues to deal with:

1. There appears to be dry rot in both the skylight head (the wood rectangle that the glazing was mounted to in the skylight) and the 2x6 framing installed through the roof below the skylight. It is likely both need to be torn out and rebuilt.
2. We cannot see what remains outside above the roof. Most skylight installations include a metal frame that wraps around the top edges of the glazing and head, metal flashing that protects the outside of the framing, and many also include a rubber membrane to cover the flashing. If a storm tore off the skylight, it may have damaged these items as well.
3. You may have more water damage to the underlayment or sheathing under shingles surrounding and below the skylight location.

While it is not hard to get a skylight manufacturer to build a skylight for any custom opening size, you need to deal with those three issues first. Given that you want to keep a skylight there, I would repair the sheathing and rebuild the frame exactly as it is now, then send a photo and exact measurements to the skylight vendor. If rain is approaching, wrap a tarp over the the opening and secure it with duck tape (although this may not prevent more water from leaking under the shingles). Also, skylights are not an easy job for a first timer. At the very least, try to find a knowledgeable friend to help.

Answer (score 0):

Any glazier can cut a piece of glass to the right size (very cheaply) and you can always silicone it into place if you want a budget fix. At least that way you wont get more moisture/rot happening and can control the current rot by painting with a wood hardener and then a waterproof paint (e.g. gloss or something).

Though clearly this is not the ideal situation so depends where the skylight is and what is underneath!

Comment: Plexiglass is another option

Comment: Common glass and hail, balls, ... may be a bad combination. Tempered or wired glass may be more appropriate.